# How to set break points on multiple functions in c in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I need to set breakpoints on each C function in a file in Visual studio.
If it's C++ it's very easy.

doing `ClassName::*` will select all the C++ functions in that file.
But how do we do it C?

For eg: my file has nearly 30 functions. Putting break point on each function manually takes a lot of time. Easier way for this?

Comment: Go to the source code window, click on the left grey margin. A big red dot appears, signalling the break point.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Sorry, Is that sarcastic? I don't understand.

Comment: No, it is not. I don't know how to set multiple breakpoints with one command; I set them one by one as above.

Comment: Probably makes more sense to set a breakpoint high up in your code and step through the program to see where it goes than setting dozens of breakpoints that might not get hit.

Comment: @InQusitive (I use VS2013 for at least 3 years but never used Class View before.) To investigate your issue, I tried to select everything in a namespace (e.g. `NS::*`). (May be, I shouldn't have tried this on the root namespace of our product solution...) VS2013 needed very long to react but then provided probably a list of all functions (and function templates) in this namespace. (I'm not quite sure - VS2013 is very slow now.) Thus, you may try to do your search with `::*`. (I recommend to "save all" before you try this at home.)

Comment: @InQusitive ...although this may not be limited to a file but to the whole project or even solution instead...

Comment: @Scheff - but C methods don't have class resolution symbol right? What does that mean then? I know how to use it with CPP.

Comment: @InQusitive OK. Scope `::` has nothing to do with C. I'm not sure how exact the VS IDE distinguishs between C and C++ (beside of to use the correct compiler). It was just an idea...